# What is the artisan command for running my local dev server as http://local.dev/test-laravel/?

Tags: php, laravel

What is the artisan command for running my local dev server from an address like http://local.dev/test-laravel/ ?

**test-laravel** is the folder in which I installed laravel.

When I run a command like `php artisan serve --host=local.dev/test-laravel/` it says server started at http://local.dev/test-laravel:8000 (which doesn't work)

Ideally the url should be http://local.dev:8000/test-laravel

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm running a XAMPP installation in a Ubuntu VM, I figured I should't have to use artisan to create another localhost address for me.

I just modified the Application Url in the app.php file and pointed it to the location where I installed laravel.

```
'url' => 'http://local.dev/test-laravel/'
```

Now I can access the public folder from URL:
http://local.dev/test-laravel/public

:-)

Answer (score 6):

One of the ways you can achieve this is by editing your Host file so the name “local.dev” can get resolved to an IP address.

This is the simplest solution and depends on the Operating System you're using.
On a Windows system you can modify your host file at `%Systemroot%\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts`

On an Linux system this host file is located in the `/etc/hosts`

In these files you can add the following DNS translation.

```
127.0.0.1   local.dev
```

Now when you try to put your server online you can use the following command `php artisan serve –host=local.dev` and can access your webfolder on http://local.dev:8000/. This won't interfere with any other server that's running on http://local.dev/ as long as the ports don't interfere.

If the port 8000 is already used you can use the following command to change port

```
php artisan serve –host=local.dev --port=8080
```

---

**Update**

Once you got the local.dev registered you can make use of it. php artisan serve won't do the DNS translation for you.

PHP 5.4.0 comes with a built-in web server where php artisan serve makes use of.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

"URI requests are served from the current working directory where PHP was started, unless the -t option is used to specify an explicit document root."

You can also configure a webserver to handle off this requests. At [Laravel.io](http://wiki.laravel.io/A_Beginner%27s_Guide_to_Laravel_4#Set_up_a_web_server) is an How-to guide.

Comment: This isn't wrong, but isn't the answer I was hoping for. I just wan't the site to run from the folder, so that I don't have to go to the hosts file everytime I have to do a laravel project.

Comment: Actually I'm running XAMPP on a Ubuntu VM and I actually needed Laravel to run in XAMPP.